# How do I animate the change of the width of a div in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have some sort of poll where you vote either YES and NO and based on the votes it creates a poll chart (by creating two divs inside another div that has a set width and setting the width of the first two divs the percentage of YES and NO votes out of the total votes). You can see the project for a better understanding by clicking [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/2yhrsf8m/).

I want it to appear animated as if it were in CSS with `transition: width 100ms linear;` just like here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .poll{
            height: 50px;
            width: 300px;
            background-color: black;
            transition: all 300ms;
        }
        .poll:hover{
            width: 500px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="poll"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, whenever I add something similar to the class of my divs I see no change. The divs in question are created in this function:

```
function renderPoll(){
container.innerHTML=''; //reset container
let poll1 = document.createElement('div');
let poll2 = document.createElement('div');

poll1.classList.add('poll-attr');
poll2.classList.add('poll-attr');

let innerTextPoll = Math.round(calcPerc()); //calcPerc() calculates the percent of YES votes with the equation percentage = (100*NumberOfYES)/NumberOfVotes
poll1.style.width = calcPerc() + '%';
poll2.style.width = 100-calcPerc() + '%';

poll1.innerText = innerTextPoll + '%';
poll2.innerText = 100-innerTextPoll + '%';

container.appendChild(poll1);
container.appendChild(poll2);
```

}

I am not nearly experienced enough to figure this out so any input is appreciated!

Comment: ‘When I add something similar’. Please make a working snippet which shows exactly how you are adding the class as the naming is different in your two examples. And what event is it in your second example that will trigger the animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bulding on your code and @Noel Maróti answer, indeed all you have to do is set interval for animating the polls after you add them to the container.

```js
function renderPoll() {
  container.innerHTML = ''; //reset container
  let poll1 = document.createElement('div');
  let poll2 = document.createElement('div');

  poll1.classList.add('poll-attr');
  poll2.classList.add('poll-attr');

  let innerTextPoll = Math.round(calcPerc()); //calcPerc() calculates the percent of YES 
  poll1.innerText = innerTextPoll + '%';
  poll2.innerText = 100 - innerTextPoll + '%';

  container.appendChild(poll1);
  container.appendChild(poll2);

  var target_length = 300;

  animation(poll1, 0, (calcPerc()) * target_length / 100);
  animation(poll2, 0, (100 - calcPerc()) * target_length / 100);

}

function calcPerc() {
  return 75;
}

function animation(elem, from, to) {
  let id = null;
  let width = from || 0;
  var speed = 2.5;
  requestAnimationFrame(frame);

  function frame() {
    if (width < to) {
      width += speed;
      elem.style.width = width + "px";
      requestAnimationFrame(frame);
    }
  }
}


renderPoll();
```

```css
.poll-attr {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 50px;
  background: lightyellow;
}

.poll {
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: black;
  transition: all 300ms;
}

.poll:hover {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="poll"></div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily like this:

```
function animation () {
  let id = null;
  const elem = document.querySelector(".poll");   
  let width = 300; // default width
  clearInterval(id);
  id = setInterval(frame, 5); // changing the number will effect the speed of the animation
  function frame() {
    if (width == 500) { // if the width is 500px, then finish animation
      clearInterval(id); // finish animation
    } else {
      width++; 
      elem.style.width = width + "px"; 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When would I call this function for it to work?

Comment: When you want to change the width